# How to make a dataset for Audio Speech Recognition of Arabic Language

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, visualization, data-science-model, audio-recognition

I am trying to map Quranic Verses for the identification of errors. Different audios for the same verse have different durations as it depends on the reciter. I used Audacity to normalize but the duration of verses cannot be normalized. Please can anyone help me prepare the dataset for training such a model?
The steps I am following are creating transcripts for each audio verse and then generating its MFCCs.
Thanks in advance.